# How can i set date parameter to previous date in a batch script?

Tags: date, batch-file

i want to delete files using batch script, the files which are older than 1 day, i want to set the date parameter in the script how can I do that?

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=/ " %%a in ('DATE/T') do set dateDOW=%%a
```

this statemenet is setting the DATE parameter to 7 days ie. if today is wed it will remove files from the last wed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
    rem Number of days ago from where to start to delete files
    set "deleteFrom=7"
    forfiles /p "c:\somewhere" /m "*.log" /d -%deleteFrom% /c "cmd /c echo del @path"
```

Adapt as needed. When list of files is correct, remove `echo` to delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in (Text.txt) do set "FileDate=%%~ta"
echo %FileDate%
```

enter `for /?` for help.

Comment: what does this statement do ?

Comment: what you intend to do with your question, imo/

Comment: sorry i didn't get you